# How can i connect to AWS transfer Family's SFTP server using diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 algrothm

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, cryptography, sftp, aws-transfer-family

I am working with hardware devices which supports SFTP protocol for file transfer. for that i have created SFTP server in AWS transfer family.

The issue i am facing is that device does not support any cryptographic algorithm that is supported by AWS transfer family

Due to that i am getting following error

> ERRORS KEX_FAILURE Message="no matching key exchange method found"
> Kex=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
> SourceIP=121.244.200.210

Algorithms which are supported by the instrument :

Key Exchange Algorithms (Kex_Algorithms)
diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
ssh-rsa
Cipher
3des-cbc
MAC
hmac-md5

These are deprecated set of cryptographic algorithm which is not supported by AWS transfer family. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/security-policies.html

Also currently there is no way to upgrade the device to change the cryptographic algorithm

what alternative do i have for making the connection.

Comment: Looks like no option. All of the device cryptos are deprecated  as you noted. I checked all 3 families and there is nothing that matches. Is the instrument no longer supported?

Comment: Thanks @RodrigoM , Yes hardware provider doesn't support this device, and couldn't upgrade firmware ....

Comment: Bummer!  What type of instrument is it? Is there some upgrade path perhaps?

Comment: Yeah ... It's basically a medical device, meant to store patient reports... which needs to be installed in hospitals... there is very limited amount of connectivity option there....

Comment: would create own sftp server on EC2 instance makes sense ? any document, reference on the same ?

Comment: 3des-cbc is known to be insecure and practically exploitable.  None of the other algorithms are considered acceptable, either.  This device is wildly insecure and shouldn't be used for private information.

Comment: While 3DES is not the most secure algorithm, that doesn’t mean that it’s going to be easy to break. Weak ciphers like 3DES can be broken via bruteforce, but note NIST allows it's use till 2023. It may take a super computer a month to crack. Possibly more computationally expensive than the data is worth. Apparently Mozilla still uses it today. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have specifically ask this question to check if there is any "Programmable" solution to overcome this limitation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider a standalone SFTP server that supports deprecated ciphers, and install it on a dedicated EC2 instance.

Check this out https://zappysys.com/forums/topic/ciphers-algorithms-supported-sftp-connection/ I think it matches your device cryptos. It may not be HIPAA approved set-up would be my concern, should you be subject to that.

Perhaps you can add compensating controls like a VPN endpoint and you could tunnel deprecated protocols though it. This would provide better security for data in transit, as 3DES is considered a weak cipher. For a security analysis see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51629/is-triple-des-still-considered-safe-to-use

Comment: Thanks a ton for your efforts ... Will start exploring the option